# Endomorphisms and Ext group

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

I'm reading a paper by Mitchell Rothstein (Sheaves with connections on abelian varieties) and he defines
$$
\mathfrak{g} = H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_X)
$$
where $X$ is some ableian variety over $k$ (algebraically closed) and then states
$$
End(\mathfrak{g}^*) \simeq Ext(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathfrak{g}^* \otimes \mathcal{O}_X).
$$
I believe $\mathfrak{g}^* = Hom_{\Gamma(x)}(\mathfrak{g},\Gamma(X))$, but Im not certain.

Either way, if anyone could show me the isomorphism above I would be very grateful, I think its probably simple so even just a hint would be great.

Answer (score 3):

I mean these are certainly isomorphic but you want a canonical one? Is this supposed to be respecting some structure I'm not seeing?

There are canonical isomorphisms

$$\text{End}(\mathfrak{g}^\ast)\cong \mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathfrak{g}^\ast$$

and

$$\text{Ext}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathfrak{g}^\ast\otimes\mathcal{O}_X)=\text{Ext}(\mathcal{O}_X,\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes\mathfrak{g}^\ast=H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\otimes\mathfrak{g}^\ast=\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathfrak{g}^\ast$$

I don't know what the purpose of all of this is though.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Sorry, how do you get the first isomorphism?

Comment: @Mathmo1123 That's just basic linear algebra. Namely, $\text{Hom}(V,W)\cong V^\ast\otimes W$.